# Split Strings In Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, split

I have a bit dirty data to handle for a `List<dynamic>`.

```
"[[1 xJeans ($100.00)$100.00], [3 xshirt ($1.00)$3.00], [1 xBermudas ($2.00)$2.00], [4 xTie ($2.00)$8.00], [5 xJeans-Red ($23.00)$115.00], [1 xJeans-blue ($21.00)$21.00], [1 xShirt-Red ($12.00)$12.00], [2 xshirt-blue ($23.00)$46.00]]"
```

This is my `List<Dynamic>` and i've to split string from it.
lets say for `elementAt(0)` we got `[1 xJeans ($100.00)$100.00]` so here `1` is Quantity, `Jeans` is my item, in brackets i have a single Unit Price and outside of bracket i have totalUnitPrice

So what i want to do is to split this data for every element and add it back to the array and want output like this

```
"[[1, Jeans , $100.00, $100.00], [3 ,shirt ,$1.00,$3.00], [1 ,Bermudas , $2.00, $2.00], [4 ,Tie , $2.00, $8.00], [5 ,Jeans-Red , $23.00, $115.00], [1 ,Jeans-blue , $21.00, $21.00], [1 ,Shirt-Red ,$12.00 , $12.00], [2 , shirt-blue , $23.00, $46.00]]"
```

Comment: so your data is a string or a list? where does it come from?

Comment: my data is in list and it is coming from s3 bucket.@pskink

Comment: actually i want to display this items in listView @pskink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `iterate` over the list and split the String into four String.

You can do something like this:

```dart
  var item ="1 xJeans (\$100.00)\$100.00";
  var first_step = item.split(" ");
  var quantity = first_step[0];
  var item_name = first_step[1].substring(1, first_step[1].length);

  var first_value = first_step[2].substring(first_step[2].indexOf("(")+1,first_step[2].indexOf(")"));
  var second_value = first_step[2].substring(first_step[2].indexOf(")")+1, first_step[2].length);

  print(quantity);
  print(item_name);
  print(first_value);
  print(second_value);
```

This will split the single inte into four usable values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regular Expression to extract the data.

Here is a Working Example based on a simple class to model your Order Items.

```dart
void main() {
  final List<OrderItem> order = data.map((itemData) => OrderItem.fromString(itemData)).toList();
  order.forEach((item) => print(item));
}

class OrderItem {

final String productName;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;
  final double totalPrice;
  
  const OrderItem({
    required this.productName,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.price,
    required this.totalPrice,
  });
  
  factory OrderItem.fromString(String data) {
    RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"^(\d+)\sx(\S+)\s\(\$(\d+\.\d+)\)\$(\d+\.\d+)$");
    Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(data);
    assert(matches.length == 1 || matches.first.groupCount == 4);
    return OrderItem(
      productName: matches.first.group(2)!,
      quantity: int.parse(matches.first.group(1)!),
      price: double.parse(matches.first.group(3)!),
      totalPrice: double.parse(matches.first.group(4)!),  
    );
  }
  
  toString() => '$quantity x $productName (\$${price.toStringAsFixed(2)}) for a total of \$${totalPrice.toStringAsFixed(2)}';
}

final data = [
  r'1 xJeans ($100.00)$100.00',
  r'3 xshirt ($1.00)$3.00',
  r'1 xBermudas ($2.00)$2.00',
  r'4 xTie ($2.00)$8.00',
  r'5 xJeans-Red ($23.00)$115.00',
  r'1 xJeans-blue ($21.00)$21.00',
  r'1 xShirt-Red ($12.00)$12.00',
  r'2 xshirt-blue ($23.00)$46.00'
];
```

*Note, instead of keeping the quantity and prices as `String`, I parsed them as `int` and `double`.*

This will print the following as a result:

```
1 x Jeans ($100.00) for a total of $100.00
3 x shirt ($1.00) for a total of $3.00
1 x Bermudas ($2.00) for a total of $2.00
4 x Tie ($2.00) for a total of $8.00
5 x Jeans-Red ($23.00) for a total of $115.00
1 x Jeans-blue ($21.00) for a total of $21.00
1 x Shirt-Red ($12.00) for a total of $12.00
2 x shirt-blue ($23.00) for a total of $46.00
```